# c:import loads different view than the one specified in tiles

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, tiles

Using:

- Spring Web 3.0.5
- JSTL 1.2.0
- Apache Tiles 2.1.4
- Resin 3.1.9

template1: imports jsp for url1
main jsp: imports /my/simple/url2
imported jsp: jsp page without imports nor includes

tiles:
logical view for url1: url1.view (extends tempate1)
logical view for url2: url2.view (is a jsp page)

Now here's what's happening:

 When accessing /my/simple/url1: goes to a controller and command which then results to
      rendering a template (template1), that imports main jsp

 Upon seeing import for /my/simple/url2, dispatches a request for this url
 This, in turn, goes to another controller using another command and renders another jsp (aka: imported jsp)

After execution of controller for url2, I expect that url2.view will be rendered and appended to main jsp. But instead of this, template1 is again rendered which results to a loop.

Did anyone experience this problem before? I'm not really sure what's happening.

Comment: Just to cross verify there is no problem in view 2 and controller command 2, are u getting any errors if you access the view 2 directly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm not sure that this will work for for earlier versions of Tiles and Spring (currently using Spring 3.1 and Tiles 2.2.2), but here it goes anyway.

I realized that for some reason, when you do an import using the core tag library within a tiles template, and let's say that import in turn calls a Spring MVC controller, it will cause an infinite loop.  The way that I got around this was by doing the following:

- Add an attribute in the tiles definition of the layout that will reference a jsp containing the code to do the import. Let's say for example:

  `<definition name="cti.layouts.fooBarLayout" template="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/foo-bar-layout.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/some-body.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="foo" value="/WEB-INF/views/my-import.jsp"/>
  </definition>`

In this example, you want to add the import code inside of my-import.jsp.  You can use the core JSTL tag `<c:import>`

- Inside of foo-bar-layout.jsp, add in a tiles:insertAttribute tag wherever you want this imported page to go.  Reference the name of the attribute (in this case 'foo'):

  `<tiles:insertAttribute name="foo"/>`

Now you can extend from this layout without worry about an infinite loop.  Not sure why this is working as I don't understand what the underlying implementation is doing, but for some reason, tiles does not allow a dynamic import to be used inside of a template page.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved by using the absolute URI of the tile. This triggeres a 'clean' request to the server and isn't aware of the current tile rendering.

I used the import because I required a more dynamic url.

So for the sample case:

```
<c:import url="/path/to/the/import/jsp/or/controller"/>
```

becomes

```
<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/mycontext/path/to/the/import/jsp/or/controller" />
```

Of course you need to update the baseURI to your applicable situation.

This avoided the recursion happening when combining tiles with c:import

**Beware: This triggers a new HTTP-request to your server.**